# How do you enrich value classes without overhead?

Tags: scala, enrich-my-library, value-class

Scala 2.10 introduces value classes, which you specify by making your class extend `AnyVal`.  There are many restrictions on value classes, but one of their huge advantages is that they allow extension methods without the penalty of creating a new class: unless boxing is required e.g. to put the value class in an array, it is simply the old class plus a set of methods that take the class as the first parameter.  Thus,

```
implicit class Foo(val i: Int) extends AnyVal {
  def +*(j: Int) = i + j*j
}
```

unwraps to something that can be no more expensive than writing `i + j*j` yourself (once the JVM inlines the method call).

Unfortunately, one of the restrictions in [SIP-15](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/value-classes.html) which describes value classes is

> 3. The underlying type of C may not be a value class.

If you have a value class that you can get your hands on, say, as a way to provide type-safe units without the overhead of boxing (unless you really need it):

```
class Meter(val meters: Double) extends AnyVal {
  def centimeters = meters*100.0                // No longer type-safe
  def +(m: Meter) = new Meter(meters+m.meters)  // Only works with Meter!
}
```

then is there a way to enrich `Meter` without object-creation overhead?  The restriction in SIP-15 prevents the obvious

```
implicit class RichMeter(m: Meter) extends AnyVal { ... }
```

approach.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In order to extend value classes, you need to recapture the underlying type.  Since value classes are required to have their wrapped type accessible (`val i` not just `i` above), you can always do this.  You can't use the handy `implicit class` shortcut, but you can still add the implicit conversion longhand.  So, if you want to add a `-` method to `Meter` you must do something like

```
class RichMeter(val meters: Double) extends AnyVal {
  def -(m: Meter) = new Meter(meters - m.meters)
}
implicit def EnrichMeters(m: Meter) = new RichMeter(m.meters)
```

Note also that you are allowed to (freely) rewrap any parameters with the original value class, so if it has functionality that you rely on (e.g. it wraps a `Long` but performs complicated bit-mixing), you can just rewrap the underlying class in the value class you're trying to extend wherever you need it.

(Note also that you'll get a warning unless you `import language.implicitConversions`.)

Addendum: in Scala 2.11+, you may make the `val` private; for cases where this was done, you will not be able to use this trick.

Comment: This seems like an oversight of SIP-15, as it directly conflicts with the saved verbosity `implicit class` provides. Are there any links to more info as to why a value class cannot have a value class as an underlying type? (compiler limitations, complexity of implementation, or otherwise)

Comment: @AlexDiCarlo - There are lots of restrictions on value classes that are not logically necessary, so my impression is that it was done to simplify the implementation.